# Is there a generic way of parsing Json in Java?

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I have tried with gson and Jackson parsers unfortunately I couldn't achieve what I wanted to.

```
{
   "rateName": "My Special Rate",
   "adjustments":    [
            {
         "adjustmentType": "LOAN_AMOUNT_GREATER_THAN_550K",
         "rate": 0.75
      },
            {
         "adjustmentType": "AMORTIZATION_TERM_LESS_THAN_30_YEARS",
         "rate": -0.2
      }
   ],
   "errorTypes": [],
   "premiumTaxs": [],
   "renewalPremiums": [],
   "totalInitialRate": 1.95,
   "optimumPricing": false,
   "miPricingVO": null,
   "rateCardId": "BALS_NR",
   "ratingInfoBaseRate": 1.4
}
```

Above is the Json I want to parse. I want to create generic methods using which I can access a value by name easily. For example:

1. getName(rateName) - Should return 'My  Special Rate'
2. getNameFromArray(adjustmentType, adjustments) - Should return
   'LOAN_AMOUNT_GREATER_THAN_550K'

Is there a way to do this? It should be generic so that this can be applied on any Json file.

Additional info: I tried using Gson, but this parses the whole file and throws an error if it finds an array.

```
JsonReader j = new JsonReader(new FileReader("Path of Json"));
        j.beginObject();
        while (j.hasNext()) {
            String name = j.nextName();

            if (name.equals("rateName")) {
                System.out.println(j.nextString());
            }
            System.out.println(name);
        }
```

I tried with jackson and encountered the same as Gson.

```
JsonFactory jfactory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonParser jParser = jfactory.createJsonParser("Path of Json");
        while (jParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
            System.out.println(jParser.getCurrentName());;
        }
```

Comment: There are libraries that eases this work like Gson and Jackson. Search on those and choose the best for your specific case.

Comment: #2 *almost* feels like a JSONPath query. Do you want to parse the data into a nested classes, or query it?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Please see my question. I have mentioned already that I tried them and I did not find any methods for the examples that I have mentioned above.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann: Query/Read it.

Comment: These libraries provide what you need but your question is like *please do this work for me, I'm too lazy to do it*. Instead, provide your attempt to accomplish your question and we'll help you.

Comment: Just searching on the net, I've found [json-path](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) that works over Jackson.

Comment: Added additional info. Thanks @LuiggiMendoza. Will try with json-path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean standard library when you say generic, then `org.json` would be that library.

Altough not as intuitive as GSON or Jackson, it is easy to use it:

```
JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(jsonString);
String rateName= jsonData.getString("rateName");//My Special Rate
```

To parse array you need to loop:

```
JSONArray adjustments = jsonData.getJSONArray("adjustments");
for(int i = 0; i < adjustments.length(); i++){
   JSONObject adjustment = adjustments.getJSONObject(i);
   String adjustmentType = adjustment.getString("adjustmentType");
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in org.json library that makes it more or less standard than GSON or Jackson -- it's just a proof-of-concept that happens to be older than other two. So whether to use that or other libraries should be based on fit for use case.

Comment: This helps.. Also Json-path is interesting too and may suit my requirement. Marking as right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hi You can use JASON READER , it readers the JSON and map the data into a MAP .

Below is the URL to Download the JAR JASON READER.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwyOcFBoJ5pueXdadFFMS2tjLVU

Below is the example -

```
package com;



     import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Map.Entry;

        import com.JasonReader;

        public class Test {

            public static void main(String[] args) {

            String request ="{\"rateName\": \"My Special Rate\",\"adjustments\":[{\"adjustmentType\": \"LOAN_AMOUNT_GREATER_THAN_550K\",\"rate\": 0.75},{\"adjustmentType\": \"AMORTIZATION_TERM_LESS_THAN_30_YEARS\",\"rate\": -0.2}],\"errorTypes\": [],\"premiumTaxs\": [],\"renewalPremiums\": [],\"totalInitialRate\": 1.95,\"optimumPricing\": false,\"miPricingVO\": null,\"rateCardId\": \"BALS_NR\",\"ratingInfoBaseRate\": 1.}";

                        //
                Map<String,String> map =new HashMap<String,String>();
                map=JasonReader.readJason(request,map);
                //System.out.println(map);
                for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    System.out.println(entry.getKey()+ "=" +entry.getValue());

                }
            }
        }
```

OUTPUT -

rateCardId=BALS_NR

adjustments|rate1=-0.2

miPricingVO=null

adjustments|adjustmentType=LOAN_AMOUNT_GREATER_THAN_550K

adjustments|adjustmentType1=AMORTIZATION_TERM_LESS_THAN_30_YEARS

adjustments|rate=0.75

optimumPricing=false

totalInitialRate=1.95

rateName=My Special Rate

ratingInfoBaseRate=1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard [JsonParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonParser.html) which is part of the javax.json package. This parser is part of Java EE since version 7 and you can use this parser without any additional library.

The parser allows you to navigate through a JSON structure using the so called 'pull parsing programming model'

```
 JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(myJSON);
 Event event = parser.next(); // START_OBJECT
 event  = parser.next(); // KEY_NAME
 String key = parser.getString(); // 'rateName'
 event = parser.next(); // STRING_VALUE
 String value=parser.getString(); // 'My Special Rate'
 event  = parser.next(); // START_ARRAY
 ....
```

But of course you need to navigate through your json data structure

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just use [Jodd JSON](http://jodd.org/doc/json/index.html) parser. You just need to deserialize the input string and the result will be collected in regular `Map` and `List`.

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
Map<String, Object> map = jsonParser.parse(input);
```

Simple as that - and the result is the most generic as it can be. Then just call `map.get("rateName")` to get your value and so on.

But notice that for adjustments you can get the way you want without some util method that would iterate elements and search for the right one. If you can, change the JSON so that you dont have an array of `adjustments`, but a map.

If you need specific results, just pass the type with the input string. See more about [parsing features](http://jodd.org/doc/json/json-parser.html).